# What is the meaning of "making a career"?

Tags: meaning

Is the phrase **making a career** true in English?
If so, what does it mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "true"? If you mean *grammatical*, you haven't provided an actual sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context, but it could be interpreted as 'rise in the world/get on in life'.

or, the meaning could be 'to be serious about it'. reference on [this site](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=make%20a%20career%20out%20of%20it)

Answer (score 0):

"Making a career" *literally* means to make something your life's work, or direction.

People tend to differentiate between a "job" and a "career" - the former being just something you do to pay the bills, and the latter being an employment direction that you decide on and actively pursue.

We use "make a career" in a number of ways, and not all are serious, or literal. For example:

> He made a career out of singing.

This means that someone made singing their main form of work/income.

> He made a career out of his hobby.

This means that someone monetised something that was a non-profit-making interest into something that earned a living.

An example where it is used *figuratively* is:

> He seems to have made a career out of offending people.

This would not literally mean someone made money from offending people, but rather that they do it so often they have become known for it.

Comment: In the sentence I have read, it is used without ""out of":  ... "making a career is essentially internal politics"